# Conditionally appending a multiple line dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm iterating a dataframe and trying to append new values inside from a different dataframe whenever a row in the first dataframe is a certain value.

Consider the following two dataframes:

```
print(full_df)
                                             AccessName                                          PolicyArn
0                                   arn:aws:glue:sample  arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/...
1                                  arn:aws:glue:sample2  arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/...
2                                                   ---  arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/...
3                                  arn:aws:s3:::sample3  arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/...


print(side_df)
                                            AccessName
0                                          sample-test
1                                         query_sample
2                                     us-east-1-sample
```

If the `AccessName` in the `full_df` is a certain value, the `side_df` is appended to the `full_df`, having the second row value always be `arn` for all rows.

```
arn = 'fixed_value'
for index, row in full_df.iterrows():
    if row['AccessName'] == '---':
        #Here I don't know how I'd define the code to append the side_df values:
        #full_df['AccessName'] = side_df['AccessName']
        #full_df['PolicyArn'] = arn
```

Would it be best to make another if statement at that point and iterate the side_df values and append row by row?

This for function is nested in the actual code and the `arn` is dynamically generated.

Desired output:

```
                                             AccessName                                          PolicyArn
0                                   arn:aws:glue:sample  arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/...
1                                  arn:aws:glue:sample2  arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/...
2                                                   ---  arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/...
3                                           sample-test  fixed_value
4                                          query_sample  fixed_value
5                                      us-east-1-sample  fixed_value
6                                  arn:aws:s3:::sample3  arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/...
```

What would be the optimal way to code this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's construct your `side_df`:

```
side_df = pd.DataFrame([['sample-test'], ['query_sample'], ['us-east-1-sample']]
                       , columns=['AccessName'])
fixed_series = pd.Series(['fixed_value'] * len(side_df), name='PolicyArn').to_frame()
side_df_extended = pd.concat([side_df, fixed_series], axis=1)
print(side_df_extended)

       AccessName    PolicyArn
0       sample-test  fixed_value
1      query_sample  fixed_value
2  us-east-1-sample  fixed_value
```

Assume `full_df` is as follows:

```
    AccessName              PolicyArn
0   arn:aws:glue:sample     arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/
1   arn:aws:glue:sample2    arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/
2   arn:aws:s3:::sample3    arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/
3   arn:aws:glue:sample4    arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/
4   arn:aws:s3:::sample5    arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/
```

Now let's grab indices of rows that have your condition, e.g.:

```
indices = full_df['AccessName'] == 'arn:aws:glue:sample2'
rows = full_df[indices].index.tolist()
rows

[1]
```

Now, you want to append `side_df` after the occurrence of your condition:

```
final_df = pd.concat([full_df.iloc[:(rows[0] + 1)], side_df_extended, full_df.iloc[(rows[0] + 1):]], ignore_index=True)
final_df

    AccessName              PolicyArn
0   arn:aws:glue:sample     arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/
1   arn:aws:glue:sample2    arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/
2   sample-test             fixed_value
3   query_sample            fixed_value
4   us-east-1-sample        fixed_value
5   arn:aws:s3:::sample3    arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/
6   arn:aws:glue:sample4    arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/
7   arn:aws:s3:::sample5    arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I've made an edit so that it fully applies to my original post.

Comment: @ire Glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

you can reindex and append the dataframes then `fillna()` as follows:

**INITIALIZATION:**

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(''' AccessName     PolicyArn
0                                   arn:aws:glue:sample  arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/...
1                                  arn:aws:glue:sample2  arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/...
2                                                   ---  arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/...
3                                  arn:aws:s3:::sample3  arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/...
'''),sep='\s+')

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''   AccessName
0                                          sample-test
1                                         query_sample
2                                     us-east-1-sample'''),sep='\s+')
```

**SOLUTION**

```
id = df.index[df['AccessName'] == '---'][0] +1
start, end = id + df2.shape[0],df2.shape[0] + df.shape[0]
df.index = np.append(df.index[:id],np.arange(start,end)) # index : [0, 1, 2, 6]
df2.index = np.arange(id,id +df2.shape[0]) # index [3, 4, 5]
solution_df = df.append(df2).sort_index().fillna('fixed_value')
solution_df
>>> AccessName              PolicyArn
0   arn:aws:glue:sample     arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/...
1   arn:aws:glue:sample2    arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/...
2   ---                     arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/...
3   sample-test             fixed_value
4   query_sample            fixed_value
5   us-east-1-sample        fixed_value
6   arn:aws:s3:::sample3    arn:aws:iam::971340810992:policy/service-role/...
```

Important Note:
generally for large dataset it is not advised to look for solutions involving iterations, try hard to find a vectorized solution, and avoid approaches like `.iterrows()` and `.apply()`. good luck!

Comment: This works but I much prefer Hoori's answer. Thank you

Comment: makes sense :) thank you for feedback anyway.